# copy specific folders and files using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line-interface, command-prompt

I'm trying to create a batch file that will do the following:

I have multiple directories and in each one of those directories there is a folder called '06-2015'. I want to create a batch script that will go thru all of those directories and copy the folder '06-2015' and its files and nothing else.

Example:

```
C:\Files\Accounts\06-2015
C:\Files\Sales\06-2015
C:\Files\IT\06-2015
```

Is there a way I can create a script that will go something like:

```
xcopy C:\Files\*\06-2015 C:\Backup\*\06-2015 /s
```

Or is there a different/better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this: remove the /s and /e if you don't want any folders inside 06-2015 copied.

```
@echo off
for /d /r "c:\files" %%a in (06-2015?) do (
  if /i "%%~nxa"=="06-2015" xcopy "%%a" "C:\Backup\%%~pnxa\" /s/h/e/k/f/c
)
```

Comment: This code works perfectly! How can I prevent this pop-up, or at least have it default to D for Directory?
**'Does C:\Backup\files\A\06-2015 specify a file name or directory name on the target (F = file, D = directory)?'**

Comment: I added a backslash to the end of this term `"C:\Backup\%%~pnxa\"` which will avoid the prompt.  The `/I` switch is almost as good too.

Answer (score 1):

A wildcard characters allowed only in the *last* path item.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "target=06-2015"
IF NOT EXIST c:\backup\%target% MKDIR c:\backup\%target%
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD "c:\files"') DO (
  if exist "c:\files\%%G\%target%\" (
    :: create backup directory if necessary
    MKDIR "c:\backup\%%G\%target%\" 2>NUL
    XCOPY /S /E /Y "c:\files\%%G\%target%\" "c:\backup\%%G\%target%\"
  )
)
```